# Loop for creating several empty csv files

Tags: stata

I need to create 215 empty `csv` files with Stata and save them on my computer.

Since this is a repetitive task, a loop would be perfect. Each file would have a similar but different name (for example `Data_Australia`, `Data_Austria` and so on).

How do I create a loop to generate several empty `csv` datasets with Stata?

I tried the *community-contributed* command `touch` but it works well when you only need to generate one empty dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a completely empty file (no header row or anything), just open a file to write to, and immediately close it again.

```
cd "C:\Users\My\Directory"
local country_names Australia Austria "Republic of Korea" // add all the names here 
foreach country_name in `country_names' {
    file open f1 using "Data_`country_name'.csv", write replace
    file close f1
}
```

If you have the names stored as a string variable, say `country`, you can instead loop through the values in that variable (in this case stopping when it reaches the end or an empty row).

```
local row = 1
while country[`row'] != "" {
    file open f1 using "Data_`=country[`row']'.csv", write replace
    file close f1
    local ++row
}
```

Comment: Your first example is missing a loop and you define a global instead of a local macro.

Comment: It works now but it is not considered good practice to use global macros.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Stuart and Pearly Spencer!

Comment: @windyboo out of curiosity why do you want to to do that?

Comment: Export some data in these files (and not, in Excel files). Identification numbers sometimes start with a zero and Excel removes the zero in these cases. Don't know if this is the right way to avoid this issue, but it works.

Comment: @windyboo you just need to use the `export` command to do so directly. You do not need to create empty files first.